# How to add a horizontal rule in align* environment between equations

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, amsmath, rules

I am trying to add a horizontal line between aligned equations.

I have tried using `\rule` command, but then the problem is that it itself takes that command as an equation, since I am using `\\` before and after this command, otherwise it is not aligning the equations correctly. With these, it uses unnecessary spaces above and below the horizontal rule. I want the output to be such that the equations are aligned as expected from the `align*` environment, with a horizontal line 'externally inserted' between two equations.

```
\begin{align*}
    y_2\times (y_2''+Py_2'+Qy_2) &=0\\
    -y_1\times (y_1''+Py_1'+Qy_1) &=0\\
    \rule{4.7cm}{1pt}&\rule{1cm}{1pt}\\
    y_1y_2''-y_1''y_2+P(y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2) &= 0\\
\end{align*}
```

The above is what I wrote, but it shows too much space above and below the horizontal rule. Even if I shift this rule 3mm upwards, the space below the rule increases and the problem remains same. Is there any way to add a horizontal rule whose space below and above can also be controlled?

Please help.

Comment: Could you please add a small example showing what you tried soe far? A sketch of the desired output could also help clarify.

Comment: @leandriis, added the code segment which I wrote. Desired output I don't have, since I could not display what I want.

Comment: Please make your code complete, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. The following may help: `\[
\begin{aligned}
    y_2\times (y_2''+Py_2'+Qy_2) &=0\\
    -y_1\times (y_1''+Py_1'+Qy_1) &=0\\ \hline
    y_1y_2''-y_1''y_2+P(y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2) &= 0\\
\end{aligned} \]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help of an `array` instead of `align*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{rl}
     y_2\times (y_2''+Py_2'+Qy_2) &{}=0\\
    -y_1\times (y_1''+Py_1'+Qy_1) &{}=0\\
    \hline
     y_1y_2''-y_1''y_2+P(y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2) &{}= 0\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You very much!

Comment: There's too much space before the `=`.  Within that equation, insert `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}` just after `\[`.  You may also have to enter the equal signs as `{}=`.  (Not tested.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks for pointing this out. I have corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: Just a bit more ... you really should enter the equal signs as `{}=`; this will ensure that the space on both sides is the same.  (It's too narrow on the left otherwise.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `aligned` and `\midrule` from `booktabs`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    y_2\times (y_2''+Py_2'+Qy_2) &=0\\
    -y_1\times (y_1''+Py_1'+Qy_1) &=0\\
    \midrule
    y_1y_2''-y_1''y_2+P(y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2) &= 0\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!